# C++ Looping with doubles

Tags: c++, loops, comparison, double

Why is PRINT THIS in the code below never printing? I've already cout << shiftx and shifty to make sure that at some point, they both are 0.3.

```
for(double shifty=0; shifty < 2; shifty+=.1) {
    for(double shiftx=0; shiftx < 2; shiftx +=.1) {
        if((shiftx == 0.3) && (shifty == 0.3)) {
            cout << "PRINT THIS" << endl;
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The golden rule is: avoid equality tests in floating-point.

Neither 0.1 nor 0.3 can be exactly represented.

Standard reading: [*What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic*](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

To solve your particular problem, you should iterate and perform comparisons using integer types.  Only convert to floating-point types when you actually need to.  e.g.:

```
for(int shifty=0; shifty < 20; shifty++) {
    for(int shiftx=0; shiftx < 20; shiftx++) {
        double shifty_double = shifty * 0.1;
        double shiftx_double = shiftx * 0.1;
        if((shiftx == 3) && (shifty == 3)) {
            cout << "PRINT THIS" << endl;
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: I understand why this works, but if .3 can't be properly represented and you try to compare .3 with .3, wouldn't they both not be able to be correctly represented and thus compare equal? Or is it that they can be 'almost' represented in a variety of different ways, and it's just chance that would make them equal or not?

Comment: @Seth That more or less sums it up. They can be "almost' represented in a variety of different ways. The literal values .1 and .3 will translate into the approximating floating point forms chosen by the compiler. Whatever the floating point form of .1 turns out to be, if it isn't EXACTLY 1/3 the value of the .3 approximation, then the equality tests in the inner loop will fail.

Answer (score 4):

This is probably due to rounding errors when using doubles since 0.3 isn't actually stored as exactly 0.3 internally.

A way to compare doubles would be to allow for some error in the comparison.
Example

```
if(abs(shiftx - shifty) < 0.000001)
```